# Problem with Maven plugin :maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce Some Enforcer rules have failed

Tags: java, maven, aem, java-11

A little bit of context:
Im working as a FE developer for an AEM project. The project is a SPA AEM as cloud service. I am running the author instance from the command line.

My pc specs are:

- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7400 CPU @ 3.00GHz   3.00 GHz
- RAM: 24.0 GB
- SSD: 476 GB
- OS: Windows 10 Pro

For the AEM Project we are using

- Java sdk 11
- Maven 3.6.3

I have already set up everything, the path variables, JAVA_HOME, mvn. All of them work fine, even trying to build other type of projects with "older" versions of AEM like 6.5 build perfectly. I don't have a problem with them. But with this version of AEM I am getting this error

```
[WARNING] Rule 9: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireFileChecksum failed with message:
There have been changes detected in a file which is supposed to be immutable according to https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-cloud-service/implementing/content-delivery/disp-overview.html#file-structure: src/conf.dispatcher.d/renders/default_renders.any
[WARNING] Rule 10: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireFileChecksum failed with message:
There have been changes detected in a file which is supposed to be immutable according to https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-cloud-service/implementing/content-delivery/disp-overview.html#file-structure: src/conf.dispatcher.d/virtualhosts/default_virtualhosts.any
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for xxxxxx 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] xxxxxx ................................. SUCCESS [  0.270 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - Core .......................... SUCCESS [ 59.232 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - UI Frontend ................... SUCCESS [ 19.876 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - UI Frontend React ............. SUCCESS [ 39.613 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - Repository Structure Package .. SUCCESS [  0.991 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - UI apps ....................... SUCCESS [ 12.990 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - UI content .................... SUCCESS [  4.178 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - UI config ..................... SUCCESS [  0.314 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - All ........................... SUCCESS [  1.052 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - Integration Tests ............. SUCCESS [ 12.166 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - Dispatcher .................... FAILURE [  0.030 s]
[INFO] xxxxxx - UI Tests ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] xxxxxx - Project Analyser .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:34 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-08-22T15:11:20-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce (enforce-checksum-of-immutable-files) on project xxxxxxx.dispatcher.cloud: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :xxxxxx.dispatcher.cloud
```

I've been searching in sites, some of the answers for this problem haven't work for me.

- I tried to run everything from the "gitbash"
  command line and I had the same problem.
- I tried to change the version in the pom.xml, didnt work.
- I tried to build the project using eclipse IDE and all the build-in tools, I get an error that **org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M3:enforce** is missing
- Disable firewall and antivirus, nope
- Use other versions of maven like 3.8.2
- Delete the **.m2** directory and download again all the plugins, not working

One of many answers tell me to comment out the dispatcher module in the pom.xml and after I did that builds fine. Other is doing the same and upload the **ui.apps/target/*.zip** with the **crx package manager** I did it but im not sure if the result is the "best".
To end, I installed the same project in a Mac Pro and i did without a problem. I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks for reading.

Comment: This is a good question, why do people tend to -1 it?

Answer (score 2):

As discussed here: https://github.com/adobe/aem-guides-wknd/pull/202

Adobe have reported the issue and the fix to Adobe AEM WKND project:

*Some Windows users experience a Maven enforcer issue where it appears that default dispatcher files have been modified. Unclear if this is a result of differences between Mac and Windows or something that occurs during the checkout process. Most users simply want to install the code base to a local environment and this check is unnecessary. Removing the enforcement for windows builds.*

so you can :

*Skips Dispatcher enforcement plugin for users on windows environments.*

doing a change you dispatcher/pom.xml
with the commit reported here:

https://github.com/adobe/aem-guides-wknd/pull/202/commits/bebcf5d2236c75a95055d5ff71ea58f66379f271

replacing the line:

```
<goal>enforce</goal>
```

with:

```
<goal>display-info</goal>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[WARNING] Rule 9: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireFileChecksum failed with message:
There have been changes detected in a file which is supposed to be immutable according to https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-cloud-service/implementing/content-delivery/disp-overview.html#file-structure: src/conf.dispatcher.d/renders/default_renders.any
```

The [Maven Enforcer Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html) is checking for some files to have an specific `checksum` using [requireFileChecksum rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFileChecksum.html)

Somewhere in your `pom.xml` the Enforcer Maven plugin should be declared, so  you will be able to see the rule and the hash it is applying. This xml snippet is from the maven plugin documentation.

```xml
<requireTextFileChecksum>
  <file>E:\java-workspace\apache-maven-enforcer\maven-enforcer\target\checkout\enforcer-rules\target\classes/foo.txt</file>
  <checksum>d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e</checksum>
  <type>md5</type>
</requireTextFileChecksum>
```

Check that hash against the hash of the file of your filesystem. Maybe when you change `aem` version, you need to upgrade some of those files.

Comment: The newest AEM archetype (project structure) has new files in the `dispatcher` module that have to keep the same content (they cannot change). In order to protect that, Adobe came up with an idea to check the checksum for those files. The problem may be you same those files in a different standard than UTF-8, like ISO, which gives you a different checksum. Check the encoding type of your editor, if you haven't changed those files at all. Otherwise, revert those changes back to the original state.